# Make a decay function for travel costs excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with costs in Colombian Pesos (COP) and another with an ID. A sample of this data is shown below.
Now i would like to add a third field with the amount of people (represented by the ID's), that are willing to pay those costs.

So the column must become something like this:

2327,5 1 1439

2327,5 2 1439

2429,5 3 1437

2429,5 4 1437

2455   5 1434

2455   6 1434

2455   7 1434

2531,5 8 1433

Please be aware that the actual data is much longer than these 26 ID's (1439 in total)

[image: Sample of data]

Comment: So i just realized I want the third colomn to state the amount of values in Colomn A that are greater than or equal to the actual selected value (also in column A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this formula in C2 and fill down the column:

```
C2:
=COUNTIFS(A:A; ">=" & A2)
```